# curvature proof

Tags: calculus

how to prove that the curvature of $\sin x$ is greatest at it's extremum  and how to calculate it?

upon derivation i discovered that extremum for $\sin x$ will apeear at $\pi/2 + \pi k$ and the same applies for the graph of curvature $q$...i dont know how to proceed...

Comment: I'm confused. You say you've found the extrema of $\sin$ and the extrema of its curvature, and that they are the same. Isn't that exactly what you wanted to find? What's left to do on the problem?

Comment: Do you use the formula $\kappa = \frac{f''}{\left( 1+(f')^2 \right) ^{3/2}}$?

Comment: that formula....

Answer (score 2):

$$\kappa(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{(1+\cos^2x)^{3/2}}$$

On Differentiation, you will get

$$\kappa'(x) = \dfrac{(2\sin^2x+2)\cos x}{(1+\cos^2x)^{5/2}}$$

$$\kappa'(x) = \fbox{$\dfrac{(2\sin^2x+2)}{(1+\cos^2x)^{5/2}}$} \cos x$$

Note that $\kappa(x)$ is maximum when $\cos x=0$

$\cos x=0$ when $\sin x$ is extremum

Comment: actually its -sinx if strictly following the formula...

Comment: or do you just take|sinx| then derive it?

Comment: oh ya, actually, if you strictly follow the formula, there will be a modulus sign. we deal the curvature function for x in [0, pi]. because its periodic with periodicity pi

Comment: cool explanation  stoic but it left me rather bewildered.